# Grails: server crashes when I recompile a file (when using datasources)

Tags: grails, datasource, jndi

I'm using datasources in my Grails project.

When I edit a groovy file with server running I get the following error:

> Running Grails application.. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must
>   supply a resource type for JNDI configuration

How can I configure `grails.naming.entries` in `Config.groovy` to fix this?

Note: I'm using grails 1.3.6

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using 1.3.7 and hit the same issue.  There's a couple bugs in the JIRA about this, looks like they were finally fixed in 2.0-M1.  There's a patch for 1.3.1+ versions here, but I haven't tested that yet.

Link to possible patch:  http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7021